# React-Native Emulator Unable to Load script problem make sure you are either running a metro server

Tags: android, react-native, react-native-ios

[photo 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bipKI.png)

[photo 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bhTXI.png)

When I try to use react native via emulator, it errors like in first photo. After I push the button called dismiss second photo appears.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure of having a running Metro server, you can launch one using :

`react-native start`